# Anti-mob houses in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are good defenses for a house in Minecraft? I know cactuses work well. Anything else?

Comment: lighting the surroundings and a 1.5 block high perimeter plus a overhang against climbing spiders are key

Comment: @SevenSidedDie most of the answers to that question are tailored specifically to creepers, and often the answers wouldn't help against spiders... I'm not quite sure if this is a dupe

Comment: yes i want anti-zombie, anti-spider, anti-skeleton house

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't need anti creeper houses because Creepers don't affect me. I want defenses for climbing spiders and for me to shoot arrows through slits in the wall and just overall fortress material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Anti-Mob House**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Safe_home)

**General**

> - Don't build out of wood
> - Use a fence or a wall to keep all mobs except spiders and spider jockeys off your lawn
> - You can create Iron Golems to defend your territory
> - Use a cactus fence built from two rows of cacti, like this:
>
>   A C A C
>   C A C A
>
> A - Air    C - Cactus (view from the top)
>
> - Build a ditch deep enough that the mobs who fall in can’t get out anymore, which is either filled with lava or streaming water
> - Keep your home area well lit. Mobs only spawn if the light level is below 7
> - Mobs don't spawn on water
> - A door made of pistons keeps you hidden from mobs almost all the time

**Anti Creepers**

> - Build a wall at least two full blocks tall
> - Build your home sufficiently lit
> - Two block thick cobblestone will resist most explosions.
> - Obsidian is explosion-proof
> - Cats are a good defense, as creepers will run away if they are in a short distance of one.

**Anti Spiders**

> - Build a lipped wall, this lip can have 1-block wide gaps in it, since spiders require a 2 block wide space to climb
> - Fences can also work as a wall-top
> - Completely cover it with a roof
> - Dump buckets of lava around your house
> - Build your buildings underground. As long as the entrance to the underground building is only 1 block wide and/or completely enclosed
>   with trapdoors, no Spiders will be able to get in
> - You can keep spiders from climbing walls using glass panes/iron bars to create an edge
>
>   C
>   G
>   C
>   C
>
> C - Cobblestone G - Glass pane

**Anti Skeletons**

> - Fill open gaps with any of certain translucent blocks such as slabs, fence or glass to make windows
> - Build low walls or fences in places where you may be in range of a skeleton, since they will only fire arrows at you if they can see you.

**Spider Jockeys**

> - Combine your defensive strategies for both skeletons and spiders

**Zombies**

> - Walls or pits will be enough to keep them at bay
> - If you're in hard, you can make a piston door so that zombies cannot get through
> - Iron door with a button on each side
> - Zombies will not jump over gaps, so you can use lava trenches
> - You can also use traps such as pits, landmines

Answer (score 0):

Personally i always like to defend a village when i find one. I do this by gathering a lot of wood and then build a 2 block high fence around the entire village. This usually takes about 64 wooden logs (4 stacks planks). After the fencing i light the entire village up with torches and later on with glowstone and awesome lava designs. If i happened to encouter pumpkins or pumpkin seeds in the dungeons i go for 1 or 2 iron golems inside the fence just to protect against any spider who happen to jump over. Just remember that spiders only attack players and not the actual villagers. if you want some more protection against spider i suggest a 3 high fence and then 1 block sticking out. i usually go for halfslabs since i find that the best looking sollution.

```
X X X X X
X B X X X
X X H X X 
X X H X X
X X H X X 
S S S S S

S = the floor
X = air blocks
H = Fencing
B = the block of choice.
```

Once you get the first iron golem your pretty much set you can also use a iron golem to just protect your own house instead of villagers.

Another method would be to get a roof on your village / house and then get a 1 block wide tunnel in and out of your house with a door or piston entrence. You could always use your imagination because its still minecraft and anything is possible.

Hope this helped,
Cheers, Marco

Answer (score 0):

For mobs other than spiders the options for keeping them away from your house are

- A wall of solid blocks with no gap that is taller than 1.5 blocks or
- A pit at least 2 blocks deep that the mobs cannot jump out of (lava optional)

For keeping spiders away your only option is a wall with no gap more than 1 block wide that also has a lip to stop spiders climbing over the top

When building your defenses keep in mind that by keeping them out you are also trapping them there to wait for you, make sure that you can easily check for ninja creepers waiting to get you as soon as you go outside.

Comment: what are ninja creepers?

Comment: @YoungGuilo http://www.personal.psu.edu/jeg5129/ninja_creeper.gif :D